How to solve [lspconfig] Cannot access configuration
I am just starting to learn Neovim so I downloaded LazyVim after watching some youtube videos and I followed those steps but now it is showing this error message after I undid the comment on typescript  and I don't know how to fix this:
[lspconfig] Cannot access configuration for golangcilsp. Ensure this server is listed in server_configurations.md or added as a custom server.
-- since this is just an example spec, don't actually load anything here and return an empty spec
-- stylua: ignore
if true then return {} end

-- every spec file under the "plugins" directory will be loaded automatically by lazy.nvim
--
-- In your plugin files, you can:
-- * add extra plugins
-- * disable/enabled LazyVim plugins
-- * override the configuration of LazyVim plugins
return {
  -- add gruvbox
  { "ellisonleao/gruvbox.nvim" },

  -- Configure LazyVim to load gruvbox
  {
    "LazyVim/LazyVim",
    opts = {
      colorscheme = "gruvbox",
    },
  },

  -- change trouble config
  {
    "folke/trouble.nvim",
    -- opts will be merged with the parent spec
    opts = { use_diagnostic_signs = true },
  },

  -- disable trouble
  { "folke/trouble.nvim", enabled = false },

  -- override nvim-cmp and add cmp-emoji
  {
    "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
    dependencies = { "hrsh7th/cmp-emoji" },
    ---@param opts cmp.ConfigSchema
    opts = function(_, opts)
      table.insert(opts.sources, { name = "emoji" })
    end,
  },

  -- change some telescope options and a keymap to browse plugin files
  {
    "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim",
    keys = {
      -- add a keymap to browse plugin files
      -- stylua: ignore
      {
        "<leader>fp",
        function() require("telescope.builtin").find_files({ cwd = require("lazy.core.config").options.root }) end,
        desc = "Find Plugin File",
      },
    },
    -- change some options
    opts = {
      defaults = {
        layout_strategy = "horizontal",
        layout_config = { prompt_position = "top" },
        sorting_strategy = "ascending",
        winblend = 0,
      },
    },
  },

  -- add pyright to lspconfig
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    ---@class PluginLspOpts
    opts = {
      ---@type lspconfig.options
      servers = {
        -- pyright will be automatically installed with mason and loaded with lspconfig
        pyright = {},
      },
    },
  },

  -- add tsserver and setup with typescript.nvim instead of lspconfig
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    dependencies = {
      "jose-elias-alvarez/typescript.nvim",
      init = function()
        require("lazyvim.util").lsp.on_attach(function(_, buffer)
          -- stylua: ignore
          vim.keymap.set( "n", "<leader>co", "TypescriptOrganizeImports", { buffer = buffer, desc = "Organize Imports" })
          vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>cR", "TypescriptRenameFile", { desc = "Rename File", buffer = buffer })
        end)
      end,
    },
    ---@class PluginLspOpts
    opts = {
      ---@type lspconfig.options
      servers = {
        -- tsserver will be automatically installed with mason and loaded with lspconfig
        tsserver = {},
      },
      -- you can do any additional lsp server setup here
      -- return true if you don't want this server to be setup with lspconfig
      ---@type table<string, fun(server:string, opts:_.lspconfig.options):boolean?>
      setup = {
        -- example to setup with typescript.nvim
        tsserver = function(_, opts)
          require("typescript").setup({ server = opts })
          return true
        end,
        -- Specify * to use this function as a fallback for any server
        -- ["*"] = function(server, opts) end,
      },
    },
  },

  -- for typescript, LazyVim also includes extra specs to properly setup lspconfig,
  -- treesitter, mason and typescript.nvim. So instead of the above, you can use:
  { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.lang.typescript" },

  -- add more treesitter parsers
  {
    "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
    opts = {
      ensure_installed = {
        "bash",
        "html",
        "javascript",
        "json",
        "lua",
        "markdown",
        "markdown_inline",
        "python",
        "query",
        "regex",
        "tsx",
        "typescript",
        "vim",
        "yaml",
      },
    },
  },

  -- since `vim.tbl_deep_extend`, can only merge tables and not lists, the code above
  -- would overwrite `ensure_installed` with the new value.
  -- If you'd rather extend the default config, use the code below instead:
  {
    "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
    opts = function(_, opts)
      -- add tsx and treesitter
      vim.list_extend(opts.ensure_installed, {
        "tsx",
        "typescript",
      })
    end,
  },

  -- the opts function can also be used to change the default opts:
  {
    "nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim",
    event = "VeryLazy",
    opts = function(_, opts)
      table.insert(opts.sections.lualine_x, "")
    end,
  },

  -- or you can return new options to override all the defaults
  {
    "nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim",
    event = "VeryLazy",
    opts = function()
      return {
        --[[add your custom lualine config here]]
      }
    end,
  },

  -- use mini.starter instead of alpha
  { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.ui.mini-starter" },

  -- add jsonls and schemastore packages, and setup treesitter for json, json5 and jsonc
  { import = "lazyvim.plugins.extras.lang.json" },

  -- add any tools you want to have installed below
  {
    "williamboman/mason.nvim",
    opts = {
      ensure_installed = {
        "stylua",
        "shellcheck",
        "shfmt",
        "flake8",
      },
    },
  },

  -- Use <tab> for completion and snippets (supertab)
  -- first: disable default <tab> and <s-tab> behavior in LuaSnip
  {
    "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip",
    keys = function()
      return {}
    end,
  },
  -- then: setup supertab in cmp
  {
    "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
    dependencies = {
      "hrsh7th/cmp-emoji",
    },
    ---@param opts cmp.ConfigSchema
    opts = function(_, opts)
      local has_words_before = function()
        unpack = unpack or table.unpack
        local line, col = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))
        return col ~= 0 and vim.api.nvim_buf_get_lines(0, line - 1, line, true)[1]:sub(col, col):match("%s") == nil
      end

      local luasnip = require("luasnip")
      local cmp = require("cmp")

      opts.mapping = vim.tbl_extend("force", opts.mapping, {
        ["<Tab>"] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
          if cmp.visible() then
            cmp.select_next_item()
            -- You could replace the expand_or_jumpable() calls with expand_or_locally_jumpable()
            -- this way you will only jump inside the snippet region
          elseif luasnip.expand_or_jumpable() then
            luasnip.expand_or_jump()
          elseif has_words_before() then
            cmp.complete()
          else
            fallback()
          end
        end, { "i", "s" }),
        ["<S-Tab>"] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
          if cmp.visible() then
            cmp.select_prev_item()
          elseif luasnip.jumpable(-1) then
            luasnip.jump(-1)
          else
            fallback()
          end
        end, { "i", "s" }),
      })
    end,
  },
}


I believe the configuration is just doing nothing because of the first line (it is just an example you can safely ignore at the moment). What kind of buffer you were editing while the error occurred (was it a go buffer?)

It would be good to have more information about what bring you to this error (what are the action you have to do to get the error). More information about the symptoms (only an error message). Do you have the problem with a Vanilla LazyVim configuration?

See How to debug my vimrc for tips on debugging

It looks like from your lspconfig that you only set up the typescript language server. If you want LSP support for Go, you'll need to configure it as well.
